# NodeJS unable to read default CAs in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ssl, certificate, ca

On our testing environment we are connecting to another server with SSL signed by our company. Every time connection is made nodejs throws
**UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE**.
I have found workarounds by setting **rejectUnauthorized: false**, but this is not aplicable in our case.

The certificates are added to **/etc/ssl/certs** and tested with the environment variable **SSL_CERT_DIR** to be either **/etc/ssl** anb **/etc/ssl/certs**, but no result.

Also, it is not preferable to add somewhere in our files the certificate and add it to every request.

Comment: Does the user running node have permission to access the certs directory? Its usually always the simple things..

Comment: This occures event when the user who runs NodeJS is ROOT and have all the permissions needed.

Comment: Have you seen this article? http://blog.gaeremynck.com/fixing-unable_to_verify_leaf_signature/

Comment: The intermediate CA certificate is also added to /etc/ssl/certs. Actualy I'm not sure NodeJS reads the certificates from the proper directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because node does not use your system's CA configuration; it includes [its own built-in list of acceptable CAs](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h).

If you want a node SSL client to accept a custom CA, you have to pass the CA's certificate in the [`ca` option](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback).

```
// do something like this when your app starts up:
fs.readFile('/path/to/ca.pem', function(err, cert) {
    if (err) ...
    else certBuffer = cert;
});

// then when you make requests...
https.request({
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    ca: certBuffer
}, ...);
```

Answer (score 3):

And if you do not want to rely on node.js built-in list, and rather use your debian/ubuntu's list :

```
var CAs = fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt').toString().split(/(?=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----)/);

// then when you make requests...
https.request({ ..., ca: CAs}, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a path to your certificates in PEM file format using the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable starting with node v7.3.0

https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file

This has the benefit of not requiring any code changes, just change the environment of your `node` process. Hope this helps!

Edit:

Also check out --use-openssl-ca https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_use_openssl_ca_use_bundled_ca

That's what I ended up using to solve my problem. I copied my .crt files to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates then ran `sudo update-ca-certificates` and then run node with --use-openssl-ca and now node finds my certificates properly.